# Magento2 order in customer panel

Tags: magento-2.1, orders

Want to show all `sales/order/view/order_id/XXX into sales/order/history/` by default **Magento** shows view order items in another page. I want to show them all in main my-orders page

Comment: any reason? if you have 50 or more orders then?

Comment: it will shows on main myorder page